# Solve a differential equation in a radioactive decay system

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, physics

I have a radioactive decay system to solve for $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ (no need for $z(t)$):
$$\begin{cases}x'=-\lambda x\\
y'=\lambda x-\mu y\\
z'=\mu y\end{cases}$$
with the initial conditions $x(0)=1,y(0)=0,z(0)=0$.

I found $x(t) = e^{-\lambda t}$, but $y(t)$ is proving to be difficult. I have tried subbing in $x(t) = e^{-\lambda t}$ so that we have a linear DE in $y$:
$$y'+\mu y=\lambda e^{-\lambda t}$$ 
but ended up getting a giant solution which seems very wrong.

Is this the right approach or no?

Answer (score 3):

The differential equation
$$y'+\mu y=\lambda e^{-\lambda t}$$
is [linear non-homogeneous with constant coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_differential_equation#Non_homogeneous_equation_with_constant_coefficients). The general solution is
$$y'(t)=Ce^{-\mu t}+y_p(t)$$
where $C$ is an arbitrary constant and $y_p$ is a particular solution. As regards $y_p$ we are supposed to distinguish two cases 1) $\lambda\not=\mu$ and 2) $\lambda=\mu$.
As a reference see the [method of undetermined coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_undetermined_coefficients#Typical_forms_of_the_particular_integral).

Once we have $y$, we can solve $z'=\mu y$ by a straightforward integration.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: We are supposed to assume $\lambda \ne \mu$. Should have said that

Comment: Then it is easier. $y_p=Ae^{-\lambda t}$ where $A$ is a constant to be found. Plug this formula into the ODE and find $A$. Later use the initial condition $y(0)=0$ to find $C$.

Comment: You do not have to solve for $z$, as the sum of the derivatives is zero, so $x+y+z=1$.

Comment: @LutzL Good point!!

Answer (score 1):

$$y'+\mu y=\lambda e^{-\lambda t}$$

$$d(e^{\mu t}y)=\lambda e^{(\mu - \lambda)t} dt \text{ }[\text{I.F.} = e^{\mu t}]$$

$$\text{Integrating, } e^{\mu t}y=\frac{\lambda e^{(\mu - \lambda)t}}{\mu - \lambda} + C$$

$$\text{Putting } y(0)=0, 0=\frac{\lambda }{\mu - \lambda} + C$$

$$\text{Hence, } y(t)=\frac{\lambda }{\mu - \lambda}(e^{(\mu - \lambda)t}-1)e^{-\mu t}$$

Comment: My suggestions are not useful anymore if one has already the full solution... :-(

Comment: This is what I did originally anyway, there was just another part to the question that turned out horribly wrong so I assumed the original solution was wrong but I guess not

Comment: @Sonjov Next time you should post your attempt. May I know the other part of the question?